# Send mail from C# code using lotuslive credentials?

Tags: c#, smtp, sendmail, lotus

I am trying to send mail from C# code using lotuslive smtp. But I have no success in sending the mail. everytime it says **{"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}**.

My code is working fine for other email hosts like gmail and yahoo.

below is the code that I have used.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.From = new MailAddress("fromaddress");
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("toaddress"));

    message.Subject = "Test";
    message.Body = "test";

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("companyname-com-smtp.mail.lotuslive.com", 465);
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

    NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("companycredentials", "password");

    client.Credentials = credential;


    client.EnableSsl = true;
           try
            {
                client.Send(message);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Outgoing SSL SMTP Server: -smtp.mail.lotuslive.com (port: 465) Please
>   Note: Outgoing SMTP access for third party email clients is not
>   available for Trial accounts.

If it is trail account then may cause some problems.

```
    MailClient = new SmtpClient();
    MailClient.Host = "smtp.mail.lotuslive.com/your host address";
    MailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    MailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
    MailClient.EnableSsl = true;
    MailClient.Port = 465;
```

If you do not have demo account then Check this link - [How to configure client in Outlook 2003](https://img-usw.mail.lotuslive.com/iNotes_help/doc/en-us/t_configuring_IMAP_POP_for_Outlook_2003.html).
Check these `outlook configure settings` match to your code settings.

If all this stuff is not the issue then it may be problem at your mail server. Check these links for information:
[An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host in SMTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575978/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)
[System.Net.Mail with SSL to authenticate against port 465](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/06/02/system-net-mail-with-ssl-to-authenticate-against-port-465.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Niranjan, I had already tried all that links before. Though the actual solution that I got was from below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082216/gmail-smtp-via-c-sharp-net-errors-on-all-ports/3845907#3845907

Comment: So is the problem solved for you? If not, are you using a test account?